# PyQGIS: hide a layers-group by uncheking it in the legend

Tags: pyqgis, layers, legend, group-layer

I have a group of layers that contain itself other groups (as shown in picture).

I need to hide one group by uncheking the checkbox in the legend.

is there any way to do it programatically using python?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For QGIS 3.x, you can use:

```
treeLayer = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layer.id())
if treeLayer:
  treeLayer .setItemVisibilityChecked(False)
```

Comment: Iam working with QGIS 2.x , so I used this :
```QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findGroup(vignette_group_inter.name()).setVisible(0) ```

Answer (score 0):

to set invisible :

```
QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findGroup(group_inter.name()).setVisible(0)
```

to set visibe :

```
QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findGroup(group_inter.name()).setVisible(2)
```

because

```
Qt::Unchecked            0  
Qt::PartiallyChecked     1 (some children are checked and some are not) 
Qt::Checked              2
```